# How do I case sum a column based on a value - 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I have the following 2 columns

```
,sum(case when Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc = 'Business and Law Faculty' then 1 else 0 end) [Business Current Year]
,sum(case when Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc = 'Business and Law Faculty' AND Apps.Reporting_Year = (Apps.Reporting_Year - 1) then 1 else 0 end) [Business Previous Year]
```

Lets say that `Apps.ReportingYear` is `2011`, how to I get the second column to sum all values in `2010`? I thought my statement would work but it doesn't seem to be.

Here is the entire query

```
WITH Equiv_day AS (
    SELECT Date_Key, Sem1_Equivalent_Day
    FROM [AUTDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Dim_Date]
    WHERE  Full_Date = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
),
Date_list AS (  
    SELECT dt.Date_Key, dt.Calendar_Year
    FROM [AUTDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Dim_Date] AS dt
    INNER JOIN Equiv_day AS ed
        ON (ed.Sem1_Equivalent_Day - 1) = dt.Sem1_Equivalent_Day  
        AND dt.Calendar_Year IN (YEAR(GETDATE()), YEAR(GETDATE())-1, YEAR(GETDATE()) - 2, YEAR(GETDATE()) - 3, YEAR(GETDATE()) - 4, YEAR(GETDATE()) - 5) 
),

PYTD_Outcome_by_Application AS (
    SELECT  
        se.Reporting_Year,
        f.Student_Demographics_Key,
        f.Application_Code, 
        Outcome_Row = Max(f.Application_Row_Num)
    FROM AUTDataWarehouse.dbo.Fact_Admission as f
        INNER JOIN AUTDataWarehouse.dbo.Dim_Intake as it
            ON it.Intake_Key = f.Intake_Key
            AND it.Prog_Intake_Type_Desc = 'Intake'
        INNER JOIN AUTDataWarehouse.dbo.Dim_Semester as se
            ON se.Semester_Key = f.Semester_Key
        INNER JOIN AUTDataWarehouse.dbo.Dim_Campus as cp
            ON cp.Campus_Key = f.Campus_Key
        INNER JOIN Date_list as dates
            ON dates.Calendar_Year = se.Reporting_Year
    WHERE f.Last_Change_Date_Key < dates.Date_Key
    GROUP BY
        se.Reporting_Year,
        f.Student_Demographics_Key,
        f.Application_Code
),
Applications_Count AS (
    SELECT

        p.Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc,
        p.Programme_Full_Desc,
        et.Enrolment_Type_Key,
        se.Reporting_Year,
        sd.Last_Secondary_School_Name [LastSchoolName],
        pr.Programme_Key,
        Campus = CASE WHEN cp.Campus_Name IN ('South','South Dist') THEN 'South' ELSE 'City / North Shore' END,
        se.Semester_Desc, 
        f.Student_Demographics_Key,
        Applicants = COUNT(DISTINCT f.Student_Demographics_Key)
        FROM AUTDataWarehouse.dbo.Fact_Admission as f
        INNER JOIN AUTDataWarehouse.dbo.Dim_Student_Demographics as sd ON sd.Student_Demographics_Key = f.Student_Demographics_Key
        INNER JOIN AUTDataWarehouse.dbo.Dim_Programme as P on P.Programme_Key = f.Programme_Key
        INNER JOIN AUTDataWarehouse.dbo.Dim_Intake as it
            ON it.Intake_Key = f.Intake_Key
            AND it.Prog_Intake_Type_Desc = 'Intake'
        INNER JOIN AUTDataWarehouse.dbo.Dim_Enrolment_Type as et
            ON et.Enrolment_Type_Key = f.Enrolment_Type_Key
        INNER JOIN AUTDataWarehouse.dbo.Dim_Programme as pr
            ON pr.Programme_Key = f.Programme_Key
        INNER JOIN AUTDataWarehouse.dbo.Dim_Campus as cp
            ON cp.Campus_Key = f.Campus_Key
        INNER JOIN AUTDataWarehouse.dbo.Dim_Semester as se
            ON se.Semester_Key = f.Semester_Key
        INNER JOIN Date_list as dates
            ON dates.Calendar_Year = se.Reporting_Year
        INNER JOIN PYTD_Outcome_by_Application AS pytd
            ON pytd.Application_Code = f.Application_Code
            AND pytd.Student_Demographics_Key = f.Student_Demographics_Key
            AND pytd.Outcome_Row = f.Application_Row_Num
            and pytd.Reporting_Year = se.Reporting_Year
            AND pytd.Application_Code IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY

        sd.Last_Secondary_School_Name,
        p.Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc,
        p.Programme_Full_Desc,
        et.Enrolment_Type_Key,
        se.Reporting_Year,
        pr.Programme_Key,
        CASE WHEN cp.Campus_Name IN ('South','South Dist') THEN 'South' ELSE 'City / North Shore' END,
        se.Semester_Desc,
        f.Student_Demographics_Key
)

SELECT 

 CAST(EP.Educational_Provider_Key as varchar(10)) as 'Education Key'
,[LastSchoolName]
,Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc
,Programme_Full_Desc
,Apps.Reporting_Year
,cast(cast(Apps.Reporting_Year as varchar(255)) + '0101' as datetime) as [YearTime]
,sum(case when Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc = 'Business and Law Faculty' then 1 else 0 end) [Business and Law Current Year]
,sum(case when Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc = 'Business and Law Faculty' AND (Apps.Reporting_Year = Apps.Reporting_Year - 1) then 1 else 0 end) [Business and Law Previous Year]
,sum(case when Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc = 'Culture and Society Faculty' then 1 else 0 end) [Culture and Society Current Year]
,sum(case when Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc = 'Culture and Society Faculty' AND Apps.Reporting_Year = 2014 then 1 else 0 end) [Culture and Society Previous Year]
,sum(case when Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc = 'Design & Creative Technologies Faculty'then 1 else 0 end) [Design & Creative TechnologiesCurrent Year]
,sum(case when Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc = 'Design & Creative Technologies Faculty' AND Apps.Reporting_Year = (Apps.Reporting_Year - 1)  then 1 else 0 end) [Design & Creative Technologies Previous Year]
,sum(case when Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc = 'Health & Environmental Sciences Faculty'then 1 else 0 end) [Health & Environmental Sciences Current Year]
,sum(case when Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc = 'Health & Environmental Sciences Faculty' AND Apps.Reporting_Year = (Apps.Reporting_Year - 1) then 1 else 0 end) [Health & Environmental Sciences Previous Year]
,sum(case when Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc = 'Te Ara Poutama' then 1 else 0 end) [Te Ara Poutama Current Year]
,sum(case when Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc = 'Te Ara Poutama' AND Apps.Reporting_Year = (Apps.Reporting_Year - 1) then 1 else 0 end) [Te Ara Poutama Previous Year]
,sum(apps.Applicants) [Total Applicants]


FROM Applications_Count as Apps

inner join AUTDataWarehouse.dbo.Dim_Educational_Provider as EP on EP.Provider_Name = [LastSchoolName]

GROUP BY Apps.Reporting_Year, [LastSchoolName], EP.Educational_Provider_Key,Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc
, Programme_Full_Desc

ORDER BY Apps.Reporting_Year, [Total Applicants] DESC
```

So basically for each programme I want a column for total applicants for the `ReportingYear` then total applicants for the `Reporting Year - 1`

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is, for a given row `Apps.Reporting_Year` can't equal `Apps.Reporting_Year - 1`.  You could use something like `YEAR(Apps.Reporting_Year) = YEAR(GETDATE())` for the current year, and `YEAR(Apps.Reporting_Year) = YEAR(GETDATE())-1` for prior. Assuming it's a `DATE` field.

Comment: @HartCO, that's an answer. So post it please.

Comment: @HartCO it's not a `DATE` field but a varchar, It has data for years 2010-2015, so for each row I want data from the `Apps.Reporting_Year` and then next to it a column with data from `Apps.Reporting_Year - 1`

Comment: @fraserjordan Perhaps some sample data and a sample of the output you're after would help.

Comment: You need to show the complete query.

Comment: Also here is a link to a picture of some data [link](http://imgur.com/piNL0yq) @HartCO

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to calculate the years separately, then self-join to get the value for the previous year.  This is the basic logic you would use, although obviously you will need to make it more complex when you adapt it to the long query above:

```
;with CTE as (select ReportingYear
  , sum(case when [condition] then 1 else 0 end) as ValueCurrYear
  from MyTables
  group by ReportingYear)

Select a.*, b.ValueCurrYear as ValuePreviousYear 
from CTE a
left join CTE b
on a.ReportingYear = b.ReportingYear + 1
```